# Conceptual graphs in a business subject PhD thesis

Tags: phd, thesis, graphics

I have my thesis ready now. I don't have many graphs apart from some for my findings. After reviewing papers and a couple of thesis in my field I noticed many of them presented conceptual graphs throughout their project. I am wondering if adding such conceptual graphs to my each chapter or specific section will make a good impact on the overall look of the thesis.

I figured out it's not an easy task. I read my thesis a few times now but I can't think of any graphs that I can make to conceptualise the main themes in chapters. The nature of my thesis is exploratory and I have narratively explained what I found.

So the question is, should I ignore the idea of making graphs? Or if it is a good idea to add graphs, what are some techniques that help in this process?

Answer (score 1):

Whether the graphs add value seems to depend on the content of the thesis. If you don't perceive what those graphs would look like, then either none are called for, or you haven't recognized opportunities to use them. In the latter case, having someone with graphing experience read and reflect on the thesis could provide you with solid proposals.

Comment: Cheers Aron, That helps!